# How do I encode/decode a custom object that has an array of custom objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nscoding

I have a custom object that has as a `property`, and `NSArray` of another set of custom `NSDictionary` objects.  When I encode and decode the array, the `NSDictionary` objects are empty when they should have value.  Everything I have read says that `NSArray` objects conform to `NSCoding`, but I feel like there must be something more I need to do to properly encode the `NSDictionary` objects within the `NSArray`...  What am I missing?

```
@interface Game : NSObject <NSMutableCopying, NSCoding>
@property int rows;
@property int cols;
@property NSMutableArray *troughs;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    // encoding properties
    [encoder encodeInteger:rows forKey:@"rows"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:cols forKey:@"cols"];
    [encoder encodeObject:troughs forKey:@"troughs"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        rows = (int)[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"rows"];
        cols = (int)[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"cols"];
        troughs = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"troughs"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The array of troughs contains objects defined as:

```
@interface Trough : NSDictionary <NSMutableCopying, NSCoding>
@property int col;
@property int row;
@property BOOL isLocked;
@property NSMutableArray *tokens;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    // encoding properties
    [encoder encodeInteger:col forKey:@"col"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:row forKey:@"row"];
    [encoder encodeBool:isLocked forKey:@"isLocked"];
    [encoder encodeObject:tokens forKey:@"tokens"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        col = (int)[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"col"];
        row = (int)[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"row"];
        isLocked = [coder decodeBoolForKey:@"isLocked"];
        tokens = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"tokens"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why is `Trough` a subclass of `NSDictionary` instead of `NSObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very unusual to subclass NSDictionary.  If those NSCopying implementations are to have any chance of working, they will need to call the inherited behavior, too.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:aCoder];
    // encode your Trough properties
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // decode your trough properties
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That was a great tip!  I realized that I didn't need Trough to be of type NSDictionary.  Switched it to NSObject and things are working MUCH better.  I didn't try calling super.  I had tried things like that at various points.  But the NSDictionary documentation doesn't say that it conforms to NSCoding, so I assumed it didn't.  Anyway, I think I am good to go now.  THANKS!!!